# What strategy should I pick when dealing with images in layouts?

Tags: android, image, layout

What strategy would you recommend when dealing with images in a layout? We all know, that android hardware differences are vast. Not only in terms of density, but also the screen sizes as well. Some mobile devices, probably most of old school days had 320dip of width, but for example Galaxy S4 has 360dip.

My question is best visualized I guess with an example. Lets say I have 2 images, that I want to display in a row (horrizonatly). How it would be best to do it (universaly, in whole projects for the most part, except exceptions):

1) Fixed width and height?
2) Width and height based on the percentage of available space (for example, with a combination of weight attribute)?
3) Making sure the images are in exact sizes before I put them in "resources", and then just display them "as they are", with wrapped_content value, and make the actual size of the image determine their space taking of the screen

In there, there is also possibility of adding different layouts, depending the screen sizes ofcourse, but I would really be glad if someone who did 10+ projects, that had dealings with images, to give me a tip, from his past expierience, what is the best long term strategy, of how to size the images in layouts.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to handling images for multiple screen densities and sizes, consider having resources specific to ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and x-hdpi seperately.

Also, it is good to use nine-patch images rather than png or bitmap images.

Answer (score 0):

Scale every image you have. 
You can use this tool to scale: [tool](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-generic.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is not general answer to your question. Instead you need to make the best design decision depending on your UI design, device/orientation compatibility and performance requirements.

For example, in a lot of cases, the design will dictate how the image will appear on screen for different screen sizes be it phone/tablet. So whether you display them as fixed width or a percentage of screen size will depend on the visual result you are after (though in this case, using scaled resources in multiple DPI buckets you can achieve similar results).

For the example of where performance is important, you may want to consider that displaying an image in its full resolution (using DPI buckets) is more efficient than getting Android to scale them. However, because you are dealing with buckets, you will have less absolute control over how the UI will appear due to the inexact nature of DPI ranges and may therefore not look ideal at certain screen sizes/DPIs.

Just to expand on what some other people have mentioned. If you haven't already, you should take a look at this android article regarding handling of resources over multiple screen configurations:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

In particular, you'll want to note that even when using weights or dp values in layouts, you'll still want to optimize your resources for as many display configurations as possible by using resource qualifiers which categorize configurations into 'buckets'. As I mentioned above, this is not only for performance reasons, but also to optimize the appearance of assests given that you'd be otherwise relying on Android to reconfigure them which can in some cases (eg. a very high res image displayed on a very low DPI device) give bad visual results.

Answer (score 0):

It really hard if you want to every device to display properly because there are 3.2 inch mdpi devices and also 5.1 inch mdpi devices. Even if u place a proper image file in drawable mdpi both devices will mess it up. So regarding images like background u have to compromise.

Better to use Device compatibility in manifest file or provide different package for different device.

For me images mainly come as replacement for button. Consider a image like a 
1 . Sign in - a wide bar of one color with text in middle of it. -  Use background color to a linear layout and place textview inside with gravity center.
2. User Selection Image, a common background and a person's image in center - in this case remove all content on image except the person. use linear layout with background matching the removed part. inside this linear layout place imageview with the image of only the person. Make sure this person image is of size matching to Xhdpi.

Now create just create different xml layout files but only one set of images. Now in different device xml mention different padding for the image and different size for linear layout.
Result will be image matching wide range of devices.

At least for me it reduced overhead of managing 20 images and almost 1Mb app size.
Hope its useful for in your case.